# How to fetching data with gRPC but not make the app delay?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to call gRPC when using camera preview with camera plugin. I call gRPC to fetch data from server every 2 second but it make my camera preview on screen stop about 0,5 second because it can not reload if my data not return yet.

I trying to use compute to make that function run in other isolate but it show this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function '_handleBuildScheduled@870399801':.)

Here is my code:

```
if (DateTime.now().difference(lastMarkTime).inSeconds >= 2){
    var person = await compute(sendFaceImage, [_faces, service, context]);

    if (person == 'unknown') {
      setState(() {
        unknownPerson = true;
      });
    }
     lastMarkTime = DateTime.now();
  }

static Future<String> sendFaceImage(List<dynamic> values) async {
if (values[0].isNotEmpty) {
  List<List<int>> images = List<List<int>>();
  images.add(imglib.encodeJpg(cropImage));
  var deviceID = App.localStorage.get('DeviceID');
  try {
    final response = await values[1].sendFace(
        listImageToListFaceRecImage(images, trackID), deviceID, 1);
    response.first.then((value) {
      print(value.result);
      Map<String, dynamic> result =
          (jsonDecode(value.result) as List<dynamic>)[0];
      personCode = result['person_code'];
      if ((personCode != 'unknown') && (personCode != '')) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            values[2],
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ResultFaceDetectScreen(
                    personCode: personCode,
                    captureImage:
                        Image.memory(imglib.encodeJpg(cropImage)))));
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {}
}
return personCode;
```

}

It seems like compute function not work with async/await because it still work with the function not have async/await.